# Parse Tab Separated Values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, clipboard, office-2007

I am trying to take clipboard data copied from excel (i.e. tab separated text) and parse it into a Collection of Dictionaries. The idea is that each row will be represented by a Dictionary which maps from headers to cell values. The first row in the copied data will contain the headers.

Getting the text from the clipboard is easy enough:

```
Dim dataObj As DataObject
Dim clipString As String
Set dataObj = New DataObject
dataObj.GetFromClipboard
clipString = dataObj.GetText
```

Then I split the input into rows:

```
Dim strRows As Variant

strRows = Split(clipString, vbNewLine)
```

Next I try to extract the headers:

```
Dim headers As New Collection
Dim strCols As Variant
strCols = Split(strRows(0), vbTab)

For col = LBound(strCols) To UBound(strCols) - 1
    headers.Add strCols(col)
Next
```

Finally I extract the rows:

```
Dim cells
Dim rows As New Collection

For i = 1 To UBound(strRows) - 1
    strCols = Split(strRows(0), vbTab)
    Set cells = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For col = 0 To UBound(strCols) - 1
        cells.Add headers.Item(col + 1), strCols(col)
    Next
    rows.Add cells
Next
```

However, I am getting an error. On the line

```
headers.Add strCols(col), col
```

Access comes back with Run-time error '12': type mismatch.

**Update** fixed the problem above, thanks for the suggestions. Now I am getting an error on the line

```
Set cells = CreateObject(Scripting.Dictionary)
```

424: Object required.

Any hints as to what I'm diong wrong - VBA isn't really my forte.

**Update 2** fixed this issue too (thanks for suggestion below). The code now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second problem -- you need provide the string name of the target class, so it's actually

```
Set cells = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the final link in the chain. Typical MSFT docs were wrong (I had copied-pasted directly for that bit).

Answer (score 2):

I think col has to be string type.

`headers.Add strCols(col), cstr(col)`

Comment: ..from Microsoft:

Public Sub Add( _
   ByVal Item As Object, _
   Optional ByVal Key As String, _
   Optional ByVal { Before | After } As Object = Nothing _
)